# Calculating graph edit distance

Tags: python, networkx

What is the difference between g.graph_edit_distance() and g.optimize_graph_edit_distance (python), in terms of what is being calculated? Also, are there other ways to get graph edit distance if the size of graphs makes g.graph_edit_distance() too complex to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

This is in the documentation for these functions. Write `help(func_name)` in Python to get the documentation. [`optimize_graph_edit_distance`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.optimize_graph_edit_distance.html)

> Returns consecutive approximations of GED (graph edit distance) between graphs G1 and G2.

Whereas [`graph_edit_distance`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance.html#networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance)

> Returns GED (graph edit distance) between graphs G1 and G2.

So the difference is that one is approximating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's what I thought, but I did both on the same two graphs, for a set of graphs, and approximation gave far higher results every time and was wondering if there was a particular bias or reason for this?